# Squirrel and crows eating rose buds and leaves of plants

Tags: houseplants

In my all balcony areas we've Indian palm squirrel, crows and Pigeons which comes and eat leaves of plants, I've searched for owl statues but at stores they tell not to keep owl statue at home hence they don't keep at it, I don't believe in this stuff so I printed out a photo of owl, gummed on a cd and hung in my balcony  but after few days there was only a cd the paper was gone. I don't like to harm these animals instead I keep water and leftover food for them. I keep it because I want them to eat that and not my plants. I've also kept peanuts for the 
squirrel but I don't know he prefers to eat my plants.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **[Azadirachta indica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica) (neem)** leaves, crushed them, mixed in water, spread on my plants. Neem leaves are bitter in taste and odour. Squirrels now just come near my plants and move away.

Answer (score 7):

Giving them food will not protect your plant, it will just attract more crows and squirrels. They are not altruistic at all and just eat what they can find that they like. This year squirrels have eaten the engine lining and insulation out of a car in my driveway. Crows have learned that plastic bags by the road may contain food (when people put the garbage out for pickup) so even though mine doesn't (we compost) they shred the bags as soon as they are put out. These are not creatures that will eat the yummy food and leave the so-so food alone, they are creatures that will learn there is always something to eat on your balcony and tell their friends somehow as well.

Get rid of the food and water. Spend time on the balcony if you can, that will make it smell like you a little more and may deter them a little. If local stores won't sell you a fake owl, order an inflatable one (to reduce shipping costs) online. I searched for inflatable owl and got a ton of hits.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the squirrels away from a certain area of ​​your home or get rid of squirrels already present in it, a bit 'of peppermint oil may be the solution.

instructions

- Moisten cotton pieces with peppermint oil, allowing each ball of cotton to be well saturated with oil.
- Place the cotton balls in the corners of the attic, outside the walls, in the garage and in any place where you want to ward off squirrels.
- Check the cotton balls every week to make sure that emanate still smell. When the smell is exhausted, replace them with new cotton balls soaked in oil of peppermint.

Alternatively, there are "bumps", electric or with battery, that are very useful as an ultrasound device (pest repeller, are fine to remove a wide range of animals why not go to certain areas). They cost 20-30 Euros and are found in agricultural stores, or on e-bay. Some have the proximity sensor so they are not always running, do not damage animals, but annoy them so they do not keep coming back to that place. But personally I have never used.

Finally, you can try to keep a cat or a ferret. They should be very affective and effective.

Comment: I'll use this trick of 'Moisten cotton pieces with peppermint oil', I'll see how it works, thanks...